# laravel 5 - sorting dates and searching the dates

Tags: php, laravel

I have a date table like below :

```php
Schema::create('dates', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->dateTime('date');
    $table->float('price');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Now I have a form that submits an start and a finish date so I have 2 variables

```
$start_date;
$end_date
```

How can I sort my date table ascending and show the dates between the `start_date` and the `end_date`?

Comment: What format are `$start_date` and `$end_date` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `whereBetween()` method:

```
\DB::table('dates')
    ->whereBetween('date', [$start_date, $end_date])
    ->orderBy('date', 'asc')
    ->get();
```

If you have a model for this table you can use it directly instead of the `DB` facade.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Eloquent like below:

```
   YourModel::whereDateBetween(‘date’,$start_date,$end_date)->orderBy->(‘date’,’asc’)->get();
```